# How can I access List type custom setting object in button click javascript?

Tags: javascript, customsetting

[image]

Here is the code..

```
if({!CONTAINS($Setup.CommercientSF3__CommercientURL__c.CommercientSF3__URL__c,',')})
{
window.open("/apex/triggertestpkg__CommonPage?page=CreateCustomer&id={!Account.Id}","_self");{!$Action.CommercientSF3__CommercientURL__c.View}
}
else
{
windows.open("/apex/triggertestpkg__CommonPage?id={!Account.Id}","_self");
}
```

I am not able to save it. please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

believe that's a restriction in Salesforce

*Formula fields only work for hierarchy custom settings; they can’t be used for list custom settings.*

reference :
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_accessing.htm&language=en_US

since its a button with onclick javascript, workaround would be to query the custom settings in your javascript

Comment: Thats what I thought. I will go for SOQL. Thanks Vamsi!!